# How to change NavBar text on login/logout in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a Navigation bar in my project which I call from inside `App.js`. Based on if I am logged in or not, I want to render different views of `NavBar`. If logged in, I want the `NavBar` to have a logout button. And if logged out, I want the `NavBar` to have login button. I use a token in `localStorage` to check if I am logged in or not. When logged in, token is present in `localStorage`. On logout/before login, there is no token key in `localStorage`. I pass this token as a state to `NavBar` as shown:

```
export default function App() {
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
   return (
      <div>
         <Router>
            <Navbar isAuth={loggedIn} />
            <Route exact path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
         </Router>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Now from `NavBar` component, I use this prop to render different views of `NavBar` as shown below:

```
const NavBar = props => {
   const classes = useStyles();

   if (props.isAuth !== null) {
      return (
         <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
               <Toolbar>
                  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                     <Link
                        href="/"
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}
                     >
                        Timetracker
                     </Link>
                  </Typography>
                  <Link href="/" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                     <Button color="inherit" onClick={auth.logout}>
                        Logout
                     </Button>
                  </Link>
               </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
         </div>
      );
   } else {
      return (
         <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
               <Toolbar>
                  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                     <Link
                        href="/"
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}
                     >
                        Timetracker
                     </Link>
                  </Typography>
                  <Link href="/login" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                     <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                  </Link>
               </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
         </div>
      );
   }
};

export default NavBar;
```

The problem is that, the `NavBar` does not update itself as soon as I login. I have to manually refresh the page in order to render the new `NavBar`. Similarly on logout too, It does not update itself and updates only on manual refresh. What is the issue and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution:
use a componentDidMount() or useEffect() function which will render automatically upon loading the NavBar page.
Inside this function, use a setInterval() function to continually retrieve the auth status (say, an interval of 5000). This will continually refresh the NavBar, and change the button immediately.
I imagine you would have to put the auth check in the NavBar component itself, instead of using props. I put the specific buttons I wanted to change in a separate component called NavBarUser, which changes 'login | signup' to 'logout' and contains a user avatar. I then inserted this component into the NavBar itself at the appropriate place.
This is what my code looks like:
```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Avatar from './Avatar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

````
const NavBarUser = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
    { /*
        setInterval was used in order to refresh the page constantly
    in order to have the "logout" button show immediately in place of
    "login", as soon as user logs out.
    */}
        setInterval(() => {
            const userString = localStorage.getItem("user");
            const user = JSON.parse(userString);
            setUser(user);
            }, [])
    }, 5000);


    const logout = () => {
        return localStorage.removeItem("user");
    }

    if (!user) {
        return (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <Link to="/login" className="nav-item nav-link">Login</Link> <span 
className="nav-item nav-link">|</span> <Link to="/SignUp" className="nav-item nav- 
link">Sign Up</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
    if (user) {
       return (
         <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="nav-item nav-link" onClick={logout}>Logout</Link>
                    <Avatar img="/images/Eat-healthy.jpg" />
            </div>
        )
    }


}


export default NavBarUser;

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) as well. From the documentation:

> Renders the first child  or  that matches the location.
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

Just like the following:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Navbar isAuth={loggedIn} />
     <Route exact path="/" exact component={Home} />
     <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
     <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Read further here: [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Router)

I hope that helps!

Comment: using switch stops rendering my other components like Home, Login when hitting their URLs. I think issue is with passing state between App and NavBar.

Answer (score 0):

Your app's state won't update if you change the value of the `token` in localStorage.

You need to make sure you update the state, I've added a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-platform-i9v6m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) if it helps.

Comment: Button in inside Navbar and not outside as your code demonstrates.

Comment: Then you need to have a function sent from the parent as props, that you will call when the button is clicked. That way you can control the state in the parent class. See [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), it should help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this issue:

To start, I created a `isLoggedIn` state in my `App` class. I gave it a `componentDidMount()` method that would fetch the login state from a cookie on app start. Then I created `globalLogin` and `globalLogout` methods as arrow functions, which set the `isLoggedIn` state to true or false accordingly. I passed my `Nav` component the `isLoggedIn` state as a prop and passed the `Login` and `Nav` routes the `globalLogin` and `globalLogout` methods. These methods can then be called from `Login` or `Nav` with `this.props.globalLogout();` or `this.props.globalLogin();`.

This is a simplified version of my `App.js`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = Cookie.get("token") ? Cookie.get("token") : null;
    if (token) {
      this.setState({ "isLoggedIn": true });
    }
  }
  globalLogin = () => {
    this.setState({ "isLoggedIn": true });
  }
  globalLogout = () => {
    this.setState({ "isLoggedIn": false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} globalLogout={this.globalLogout}/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" exact>
              <Login globalLogin={this.globalLogin}/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: using history.push didn't work in login module above so I added an intermediate to handle props

```
render() {
    const LoginIntermediate = (props) => {
      return (
        <Login {...props} globalLogin={this.globalLogin}/>
      )
    }
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} globalLogout={this.globalLogout}/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginIntermediate} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```